# How to prevent a key from being held down on a button? C#

Tags: c#, events, button

I am writing a game where you need to click a button as many times as you can in 10 seconds. The problem is that it is possible to hold the Enter key down to superspeed the counter.

How can I prevent this? I tried KeyDown Events but it doesn't seem to fire when the key is held down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MouseClick` event as that only captures clicks by the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

try handling `KeyPress` instead of `KeyDown`.